# Regex for matching html tags with escaped characters

Tags: .net, regex

I'm using regex to help me filter out HTML in a localisation project that I don't want to translate. Normally I use `</?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?>` but  the content I'm translating has escaped characters in the HTML such as

```
<a href\="http\://www.fau.de/studium/zulassung/einschreibung/" target\="_blank"     title\="Externer Link auf die Webseite der FAU">
```

Can some kind soul help me work out how to match html tags containing slashes where they shouldn't really be?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1

Comment: HTML is *not* a regular language.  Don't use regex for parsing HTML.  Use the HtmlAgilityPack or some other library.

Comment: Do you have to use regex? Regex is not the best tool for HTML. Find an HTML parser.

Comment: In your example, only the `=` equals sign is escaped. Where else will escaped chars hide out? Attribute name? Attribute value? Element tag name?

Comment: I understand I shouldn't be parsing HTML with Regex. I used ´/<(.|\n)*?>/g´ to match all HTML tags in my text and this worked for me for ignoring this content. I hadn't been clear enough about what I was trying to do but I learnt a lot from the other posts on the way - my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I used ´/<(.|\n)*?>/g´ to match all HTML tags in my text and this worked for me for ignoring this content.